# Batch File will run from command line, but not Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, task-scheduler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W077K.jpg)I have several computers, all running Windows 10 Pro x64.  All were upgraded from Windows 7/8 via the Microsoft free upgrade offer of more than 1 year ago.

One of these systems is where I store all of my client created content (docs, pics, music, etc.) – DT1.  Another is used as a file and multimedia server – S1.  Since I have a lot of disk storage on S1, I use it as backup system too.

First I cycle through 7 folders, bringing the oldest backup forward and bumping the other 6 back in sequence of newest to oldest.  Then I use Robocopy to mirror my content files to the current first folder in the sequence of 7.

```
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC" ABCX
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC7" ABC
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC6" ABC7
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC5" ABC6
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC4" ABC5
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC3" ABC4
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC2" ABC3
Rename "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABCX" ABC2
```

`Robocopy "\\DT1\D\RCY" /MIR "N:\My Backups\RCY\ABC\DT1"`  (I know I don’t need to quotes around destination name as there are no spaces or special characters, but it is just easier to be consistent).

This has worked for more than a year, running nightly.  When the motherboard in S1 failed recently, I decided to defer repairing it immediately and built a new system so I could increase my storage options/capacity.  I named the new system S1 and assigned it the same IP address of the original S1 and also made sure all the drive letters were as previous.  This new system is the only one with a direct retail Win 10 Pro x64 install – version 1803.  DT1 is also running version 1803, but it got there via Windows Update.

But now, even though the batch file executes perfectly from the command line, it will not execute from Task Scheduler (TS) – neither manually nor on a schedule.  As far as I can tell it doesn’t even rename the destination folders – the steps before Robocopy is supposed to execute.  The TS job is set to use the highest privileges and runs from my account with Administrator privileges.  When executed it states it is running, but nothing happens.  After 4 hours it cancels (my setting – from the command line it completes in under 5 minutes).
I have rebooted S1 to make sure nothing else is accessing the folders\files.
I have even tried enabling the Administrator account and running it from there – same result.
I have given full access to the files to every account type, including “Everyone.”

I complied the batch files into an exe file, set that to run as Administrator, but nogo.

Any ideas what else to try?  Again, please remember that it all worked flawlessly until I simple introduced a new system and OS install.  And that it runs as it should from the command line.

I know I can find ways to work around this (XCopy, etc.), but I’m looking for a solution to this TS problem as I find that learning the answer to a thorny technical issue pays dividends later.

Comment: is N:\ a mounted drive or physical drive in the machine? I had the same issues and it was that with network drives, you have to give full UNC paths instead, ie: \\server\share\ and then it would work

Comment: What is your TS command, exactly? Have you preceded it with `cmd /c`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it states it is running", do you mean you added some debug code. Do you see any traces of the task in the Event Viewer? I think you should also include in your post screenshots of the scheduled task's definition.

Comment: N: is a mounted driver on S1.  I use a full UNC path for the source files.  FYI - the TS job runs on S1 as a pull.  But I also tried it on DT1 as a push with the same results, or lack there of.

For the TS job, under the 'Actions'  tab I have 'Start a Program' and browsed to the batch file.  This worked perfectly until I upgraded S1 to new equipment.

I'm not seeing where I can post screenshots.  I'll try to edit my original post.

When you look at the job in TS, it shows 'Running' under the 'Status' column/header.

Comment: I just went back and edited my original post and added 6 screenshots, but I don't see them....

Comment: There is probably a size/resolution requirement for image files, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: As stated, do not use mounted drives in batch files or anything else that runs in the background. You have no way of guaranteeing those drives will be present in the context that the script runs. Rather than get in to technical details of why, just don’t do it. Don’t use N:, use the UNC path to N:. I’m sure your batch file is hanging waiting for you to respond to an error that says the file/path does not exist or that you don’t have access.

Comment: The drive N: is not a shared drive on the network.  It is a local drive on S1 with the drive letter assigned by the system and where the batch file and TS job execute.

Comment: I believe I misunderstood the original question about mounted vs physical.  It is a physical drive inside the S1 tower.